# Nativescript: runtime exception on tns run

Tags: nativescript

When I execute tns run android to test my code, it produces this runtime error:

```
Gradle build...
         + setting applicationId
         + applying user-defined configuration from C:\Users\Ace\eclipse-workspace\arenamaster\App_Resources\Android\app.gradle
         + using android X library androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
         + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized-with-inspector
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Class not found org.nativescript.widgets.image.Worker.OnImageLoadedListener
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.getClass(Generator.java:549)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.getInterfacesFromCache(Generator.java:532)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.writeBinding(Generator.java:283)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.generateBinding(Generator.java:171)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.processRows(Generator.java:234)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.generateBindings(Generator.java:121)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.writeBindings(Generator.java:97)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Main.main(Main.java:53)
```

I have tried the following:
Deleting my .tns.ts files and reverting code splitting
Migrating the project to androidX
Deleting the platforms directory then running tns run android

Comment: That class is still valid and internally used with latest tns core modules. Does this happen after launching the app?

Comment: No, it happens during the gradle build before the app launches.

Answer (score 0):

nativescript core modules requires a package called nativescript core modules widgets

If you get this error run `npm i nativescript-core-modules-widgets`

Comment: the package is called `tns-core-modules-widgets` now

Answer (score 0):

Just noting that with NativeScript 7.x and higher, the answer from @ace zhang is no longer needed. All that's needed is:

"@nativescript/core": "^7.0.0"